# how to use cookie-free domains (yslow)

Tags: set, subdomain, yslow

I was trying to solve the problem with `cookie-free`, the `yslow` has suggested to create a subdomain. I did, but the `yslow` still "show" the problem.

i didn't set the cookie´s domain in the page, cause i don't know how to do it.

anyone know a tutorial or a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 11):

Create a subdomain such as static.yourwebsite.com which is where you will deliver all your static files from.

Point your new subdomain to the /wp-content directory for a WordPress installation.

For cPanel users, you will need to update the document root field from public_html/static to public_html/wp-content like the screenshot below. cpanel document root

Edit your config.php file to reflect the following:

define("WP_CONTENT_URL", "http://static.yourwebsite.com");

define("COOKIE_DOMAIN", "www.yourwebsite.com");

Now that your cookie domain and static content subdomain are set, you can begin delivering static content without the server setting an unnecessary cookie for static assets.

https://www.keycdn.com/support/how-to-use-cookie-free-domains/

Comment: should i install new word press for http://static.yourwebsite.com" or same wordpress of www.yourwebsite.com/wp-content?

Comment: config.php = wp-config.php

Answer (score 5):

To work around this problem, make sure that static components are requested with cookie-free requests by creating a subdomain and hosting them there.

If your domain is `www.example.org`, you can host your static components on `static.example.org`. However, if you've already set cookies on the top-level domain example.org as opposed to `www.example.org`, then all the requests to `static.example.org` will include those cookies.

In this case, you can buy a whole new domain, host your static components there, and keep this domain cookie-free.

Yahoo! uses `yimg.com`, YouTube uses `ytimg.com`, Amazon uses `images-amazon.com` and so on.

[Read More](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#cookie_free)

Answer (score 1):

Serve static content from a different domain to avoid unnecessary cookie traffic.
When the browser requests a static image and sends cookies with the request, the server ignores the cookies. These cookies are unnecessary network traffic.

1. Move all your static content on a different domain, where no cookies
   are set.
2. Move your static content on a different sub domain and set 
   all the cookies to the www subdomain.